# Bewohner der Insel Lesbos

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request, terminology

Wie ist die offizielle Bezeichnung für die Bewohner der Insel Lesbos?

Comment: http://www.spiegel.de/reise/europa/aegaeis-insel-drei-lesbier-wollen-bezeichnung-lesbisch-verbieten-a-550496.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die korrekte Bezeichnung in deutscher Sprache lautet "Lesvioten" oder "Lesvonier".

Der Name "Lesbe" oder "Lesbierin" leitet sich allerdings tatsächlich vom Namen dieser Insel ab.

Comment: Lesvier und Lesbier geben ein und das selbe griechische Wort Λέσβιος wieder. Einmal wurde das beta als B wiedergegeben, einmal als V. Nach gängigen Theorien begann das Beta sich im zweiten Jahrhundert Richtung w zu verschieben.

Comment: Da du von der 'offiziellen Bezeichnung' schreibst: gibt es eventuell einen Link zum offiziellen Dokument, in dem das festgeschrieben ist?

Comment: "Offiziell" ist irreführend, ich habe es ersetzt. Ludi hat den Hinweis auf die neugriechische Schreibweise gegeben. Die genannten Begriffe findet man in vielen Quellen wie Reiseführern usw. und entsprechen der deutschen Schreibweise.

Answer (score 4):

#### Mytilener

Auch möglich ist dieser schon ältere Begriff, der vor allem in Berichten der [altgriechichen Geschichte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittakos) vorkommt, und nach der Hauptstadt von Lesbos benannt ist. Die Inselbewohner selbst grenzen sich mit diesem Begriff von den  *Lesbiern* ab: **Μυτιληναίοι**.

Answer (score 2):

Die Bezeichnungen lauten *»der [Lesbier](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Lesbier)«* und *»die [Lesbierin](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Lesbierin)*«.

Plural: Die Lesbier und Lesbierinnen.